# Is there any methods to import a .fbx(autodesk) file by slice?

Tags: autodesk, fbx

I'm using autodesk fbx to import .fbx file into my scene. The problem is that it'll take a really overwhelmed memory if I import the whole .fbx file at once with FbxImported->Initialize, and my machine will crash.

Is there any methods to import the .fbx file by slice? I just import a part of the whole .fbx file(some skeletons), handle it immediately and release the memory. Then I load the following part to avoid crashing.

I know there is a FbxStream type of FbxImported->Initialize. Is that possible to use this FbxStream to realize the segmented reading? Or are there any other methods to deal with my problem?